# Can't Pin a ParseRelation Query result in LocalDataStore?

Tags: android, parse-platform

On my application I observe a strange behavior.
I have a Class with a ParseRelation of "Users".
I query this Relation like this:

```
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = this.obj.getRelation("users");
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = relation.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", anObjectId);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
       @Override
       public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
           if (e != null) {
               log("error in find : " + e);
           } else {
               if (!objects.isEmpty()) {
                   ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(objects)
```

The Object is found (because it in in Relation from the remote database)
Then I call the same query but adding

```
query.fromLocalDatastore();
```

But the object is not found from the localDataStore cache.

**Can someone explain me why; and if it is possible to store the result of a ParseRelation query in localDataStore?**

[EDIT]:
for info the Parse Initialisatin is done like this:

```
      Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(context)
                    //.applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
                    //.clientKey("YOUR_CLIENT_KEY")
                    .server(hostServer)
                            //.server("https://parseapi.back4app.com/")
                    .enableLocalDataStore()
                    .build()
    );
```

AppId and Client ID are put directly in the Android Manifest file

Comment: Did you set ACL's to your objects or not ?

Comment: ACL for Users is : Public read, owner read/write. If I use classic Query I can store them in the localDatastore, but not I I query them from ParseRelation

Comment: you are using parse.com or parse-server?

Comment: actually I think parse-server (throught Back4App provider)

Comment: ok cool. can you show me how you initialize the parse android SDK  ?

Comment: Why you didn't specify app Id ?

Comment: When you are trying to pin the objects do you get any error? can you please call this function with callback to make sure you did not get an error while trying to pin those objects ?

Comment: yes no Error during the Pin

Comment: this is very strange .. and it's not return results only from this query or in all of your queries ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120764/discussion-between-toofoo-and-ran-hassid).